How do I solve this issue of osgi bundle not started?
I'm running a build of an Eclipse plugin. Previously, I only had this issue on the CI servers of Github, and I did not have it locally on my desktop. But the issue started appearing also on my computer.
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:4.0.1:publish-osgi-ee (default-publish-osgi-ee) on project org.scala-ide.zinc.update-site: Publisher failed. Verify your target-platform-configuration and executionEnvironment are suitable for proper resolution: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository is not started -> [Help 1]

I have checked the status of the bundle in the console. So I don't know what's wrong:
g! ss org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository

id      State       Bundle
234     ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.8.100.v20240207-1113
235     STARTING    org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools_2.4.300.v20240207-1113
g!


How you are able to check the status of the bundle in the Tycho build? Please upgrade your Tycho from 4.0.1 to 4.0.7 and provide a minimal reproducible example, including the POM and the target definition file (see error message: Verify your target-platform-configuration and executionEnvironment are suitable for proper resolution). Especially, look at this part of your POM.

It was Indeed the tycho version. Probably a bug from version 4.0.1 ?

Yes, it seems so: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/discussions/3738 Glad it works now. Please consider to give a self-answer.

I updated the tycho version to 4.0.7 and the error disappeared.
It seems to be a bug from version 4.0.1.
https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/discussions/3738
